# How to convert a script-lab example to Visual Studio 2019 Community project

Tags: office-js, scriptlab

Say I want to convert "Basic API call (TypeScript)" Word Add-in sample to a Visual Studio project. What are the steps for a newbie, in particular for people new to installing, setting up, and using technologies like jQuery, WebPack, Typescript.

In particular, I assume that

- contents of the "Script" tab goes to, say "Home.ts",
- contents of the "HTML" tab goes to "home.html",
- and contents of the "CSS" tab goes to "home.css".

Then where does the contents of the "Libraries" tab go?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should call the libraries with `<script>` tags in home.html. You may find that the autogenerated home.html already has some or all of them.